# How to get shared database url in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

How to get SHARED_DATABASE_URL in heroku.. while am trying to migrate it is asking for SHARED_DATABASE_URL how can i get it.. ??

```
heroku pg:reset --db SHARED_DATABASE_URL
```

What should i add in the place of SHARED_DATABASE_URL?? am working in ruby on rails

could anyone help me on this.

Comment: [This][1] helped me! I missed one part of the Code snippets!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172901/undefined-local-variable-or-method-current-user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use command: `heroku pg:info` or just `heroku pg` to get information about your database. You will get something like this:

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY_URL (DATABASE_URL)
```

Then run: `heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY_URL`

to reset database on heroku.

Comment: ya am getting the same as you given above..so should i give DATABASE_URL in place of SHARED_DATABASE_URL??

Answer (score 0):

The instruction below worked for me :

```
$ heroku pg:credentials YOUR_DATABASE_NAME
```

It returns the informations ( url, port, dbname, user, password ) :

```
Connection info string:
```

"dbname=xxxxxxx host=dc2-103-73-245-224.shhdtdr-1.amazonaws.com port=6212 user=user31231 password=dyzjur sslmode=require"